# Remove duplicate based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
timestamp            |  expectedValue   |   value    |  name
2020-04-01T00:00:00Z          0         |     231    |    a
2020-04-01T00:00:00Z          1         |     324    |    a
2020-04-01T00:00:00Z          0
2020-04-02T00:00:00Z          0
2020-04-02T00:00:00Z          1
```

I want to remove the duplicate that has 0 as expectedValue and keep the other one.

What would be the best way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you expect with below code line:

```
df = df.iloc[df.expectedValue.ne(1).argsort(kind='mergesort')].drop_duplicates(['timestamp'])
```

Which drops duplicates by timestamp column and returns only rows that have value column different from 0.

### Toy example code

Below toy example code works as you expect:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([\
["2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",0,231,"a"],\
["2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",1,324,"a"],\
["2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",0,np.nan,np.nan],\
["2020-04-02T00:00:00Z",0,np.nan,np.nan],\
["2020-04-02T00:00:00Z",1,np.nan,np.nan]],\
columns=["timestamp","expectedValue","value","name"])

df = df.iloc[df.expectedValue.ne(1).argsort(kind='mergesort')].drop_duplicates(['timestamp'])
```

And the result is:

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
              timestamp  expectedValue  value name
1  2020-04-01T00:00:00Z              1  324.0    a
4  2020-04-02T00:00:00Z              1    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to drop `expectedValue = 0` on duplicated of `timestamp`. I.e., on single(non-duplicated) timestamp of `expectedValue = 0`, you want to keep them.

Try this:

```
m = df.expectedValue.ne(0)
m1 = df.timestamp.duplicated(keep=False)

df_final = df[~m1 | (m1 & m)]

Out[96]:
              timestamp  expectedValue  value name
1  2020-04-01T00:00:00Z              1  324.0    a
4  2020-04-02T00:00:00Z              1    NaN  NaN
```